# How will PHP finally save session info with the code below?

Tags: php, session

```
ini_set("session.save_handler", "memcache");
ini_set("memcache.hash_strategy", "consistent");
ini_set("session.save_path", "tcp://192.168.202.112:11053");
```

Can anyone illustrate?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear… What do you mean by "how will PHP finally save session info"?

Comment: How will PHP deal with `session.save_handler` and `session.save_path` finally?

Answer (score 0):

The memcache extension comes with a built-in session handler that's set by the first line and that understands the other lines. More information can be found in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/memcache.ini.php#ini.memcache.hash-strategy).